# elements in a foreach loop getting different css/bootstrap styles in laravel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

am getting this weird bug whereby css styles are only applying to the first 2 items in my foreach loop.here is my code.

//html code

```
<div class="row">
@if ($housescategory->isEmpty())
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        No houses Found At the Moment
    </div>
@else 

    @foreach ($housescategory as $rentalhse)
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <section class="card hsecard">
            <figure>
                <div class="img-overlay hot-home">
                    @if($rentalhse->vacancy_status==1)
                        <span class="badge badge-info p-2 rounded-0 statusbadge">Vacants Available</span>   
                    @elseif($rentalhse->vacancy_status==2)
                        <span class="badge badge-success p-2 rounded-0 statusbadge">Fully Booked</span>
                    @endif
                    
                    <img src="{{ asset ('imagesforthewebsite/rentalhouses/rentalimages/medium/'.$rentalhse->rental_image) }}" alt="{{ $rentalhse->rental_name }}">
                </div>
                {{ $rentalhse->id }}<figcaption>{{ $rentalhse->rental_name }}
                </figcaption>
                <div class="pricelocation" style="display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;">

                    <section class="location">
                        <a class="disabled font-italic h6"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>{{ $rentalhse->houselocation->location_title }}</a>
                    </section>
                    <section class="pricelink">
                        <span class="btn btn-dark">sh.{{ $rentalhse->monthly_rent }}</span>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </figure>
            <div class="card-content">
                <p>{!! Str::limit($rentalhse->rental_details, 80)!!}</p>

                <section class="icons-home">
                    <div class="name-icon">
                        @if ($rentalhse->cctv_cameras == 'yes')
                            <span>CCtv Security Cameras</span>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>
                                <span>Available</span>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="name-icon">
                        @if ($rentalhse->parking == 'yes')
                            <span>Parking</span>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class='fas fa-parking'></i>
                                <span>Available</span>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="name-icon">
                        @if ($rentalhse->generator == 'yes')
                            <span>Backup Generator</span>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
                                <span>Available</span>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            <div class="viewprice" style="display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between; margin:0px !important;">
                    <section class="viewlink">
                        <a href="#" id="requesthouse" class="btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="{{ $rentalhse->id }}">Contact Admin</a>
                    </section>
                    <section class="viewlink">
                        
                        <a class="btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{ url('rentalhse/'.$rentalhse->rental_slug.'/'.$rentalhse->id) }}" role="button" >
                            View Details
                        </a>
                    </section>
                </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

here its how it looks like in the page [image: parta].here the paragraph starts getting itaicised which is a different style from the first one.. here is the other part [image: nexpart] here the column gets smaller different from the set one in the row.its been giving me headache  i havent understood why its coming up.

Comment: So when you check the generated HTML resp. the resulting DOM, that last element still has the `col-lg-4` class? Presumably yes, so go check what CSS actually applies to it.

Comment: @CBroe yes it has that class as the others..on inspecting the elements i have seen the styles are similar to those of other colmns in the row

Comment: What do you mean by "similar"? Inspect the paragraph and look for the `font-style: italic`, it's got to be assigned somewhere. Maybe a rogue `:nth-child()`?

Comment: @tobiv yes i have found it..but it comes as  user agent styesheet